# How to prove a set is closed?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Given a sequence in the Real Numbers, there is an arbitrary subsequence and the set

[image]

Comment: First, check the definition of the closed set.

Comment: Is the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{R}$? You need to show that it contains all of its limit points. Let $(d_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq D$ be a sequence. $D$ is closed if and only if $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} d_n$ exists implies $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} d_n \in D$ for any choice of sequence $d_n$.

Comment: The OP means: let $(a_n)_{n}$ be a sequence in $\Bbb R$. Define $D$ based on that fixed sequence: all its subsequential sublimits. Then $D$ is closed. $D$ could be a single pont, if $\underline{a}$ is a constant sequence or $\Bbb R$, if we enumerate $\Bbb Q$. In fact we can have any closed subset $A$ in $\Bbb R$, if we like, depending on the sequence we choose. @InterstellarProbe

Comment: @HennoBrandsma huh? I gave the definition of a closed set. Why are you talking about enumerating $\mathbb Q$?

Answer (score 2):

Let us prove that $R - D$ is open. Let $a \in R-D$. If for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ does exists an $k(n) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_{k(n)} \in B(a,\frac{1}{n})$ we could conclude that $a \in D$ because the sequence $(a_{k(n)})$ converges to $a$. This contradicts the ipotesis and thus there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $B(a,\frac{1}{n_0}) \cap \{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}= \emptyset$. From that it is easy to infer $B(a,\frac{1}{n_0}) \subseteq R-D$. The assert follows.